# For some reason, PHP shows up in my textarea box

Tags: php, html

Here's my code:

```
<textarea>
<?
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0], $row[1] . "\n";
    ?>
</textarea>
```

And it outputs this to the textarea box AND creates a second box:

```
<?
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0], $row[1] . "\n";
    ?>
```

With long tags and the curly brace, I now get this! Haha:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\globaldetroit\index.php on line <i>23</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>672248</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\globaldetroit\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0037</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>679240</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array' target='_new'>mysql_fetch_array</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\globaldetroit\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>23</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

When I removed my "ordered by" statement in my SQL code, this error disappeared.

Comment: it seems you are still pulling your idea of editing whole database contents in one textarea. If i were your father...

Comment: anyone remember when whole websites looked like that error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, short tags might be disabled on your server:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[0], $row[1] . "\n";
?>
```

**Edit:**

Your missing a closing `}` for the `while` loop:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[0], $row[1] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well that seemed to work, sorta, now I have this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\globaldetroit\index.php on line 34

Comment: Oh and Hi Jake from another Jake.

Comment: Hi! Question though - that } worked, however if I have "ordered by" in my SQL, it causes an error! What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

either short_open_tag is set off or PHP is not running

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<textarea>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0], $row[1] . "\n";
}
?>
</textarea>
```